# How do you Bulk Test URL Redirections?

Tags: selenium, curl, redirect, http-redirect

Like many others on SO, I am not from a hardcore dev background - far more ops. Therefore I find myself struggling with something like this which I guess belongs very much here.

Requirement - I want to easily test large (1000-50000) batches of URL Redirections. Closer to the former.

**Inputs I want to give**

- Source URL & Target URL

**Outputs I want to... umm get out**

- Pass/Fail
- HTTP Response Code

***Bonus points for*** - Using real browsers (Selenium et al) as a very small proportion of redirects are done in JS. Very small. Being able to choose if Target URL equates to the first redirect or the penultimate one. Being able to easily change HTTP Headers (though happy to inject those with Fiddler etc)

**Ideas I have currently**

- Bash script calling curl. I can do this but my problems are being able to make it scale i.e. parsing a csv input rather than manually editing a script. Also it doesn't cover the JS redirects (no dealbreaker). Seems like the easiest option.
- Selenium IDE script. I probably could write the script but again struggling to scale it to even 10 URLs. Probably have to parse a CSV to create each script and then feed those into the command line runner and then capture the output.
- Screaming Frog. I actually really love this tool and it can test redirections in bulk. However it has no concept of pass/fail. So close to being a one-stop shop. Also the free version doesn't follow redirection chains (i.e. -L in curl)

Just seems like one of those problems others must have had and tackled in a mainstream/easier way that I have thought of. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to StardustOne but I felt that I MUST be reinventing the wheel a little.

Ignoring the requirement to test in-browser and cover JS scenarios I looked again and the nicest solution I have found to-date was something sent out in the Devops Weekly newsletter

Smolder - https://github.com/sky-shiny/smolder

I know a member of staff working for one of our vendors was also working on a similar app that wrapped the Python requests library and I plan to back-to-back the two soon to find out which is actually best. I'll post back if his effort beats Smolder!

Comment: Anything to report?

Answer (score 2):

One solution :

#### csv:

```
http://google.com;http://www.google.fr
http://domain.null;http://www.domain.null
```

#### code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=";" read -r url1 url2; do
    ret=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" "$url1")
    ((ret >= 200 && ret <= 400)) && echo 'url1 PASS' || echo 'url1 FAIL'
    echo "url2 $(curl -s -L -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" "$url2")"
done < csv
```

If you need to know the real URL redirected (or not), use

```
curl -L -s -o /dev/null http://google.fr -w "%{url_effective}\n"
```

Feel free to improve to fit your needs.

Comment: That was a superb start Sputnick and I tried to adapt it but I'm missing one major edge case which is the PASS/FAIL is judged from the HTTP Response code. If your URL hits the wrong redirection (but still hits a redirection) then it's not spotted.

I'm struggling to get that final piece and I guess it involves using more params in the -w , then assigning each into variable, then a bit comparison between the variable and the expected. Running out of talent at the moment. Also no big deal but that might enable just 1 redir to power the whole thing instead of 2.

Comment: Added code to know the effective URL, I don't get exactly what you need. You have a very good English but there's to much noise (a kind of TL;DR), I prefer sample input/output, it's easier to understand =)